# How to get total quantity we have in each warehouse using MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with the below documents:

```
{ item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
{ item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
{ item: "paper", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 60 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 } ] },
{ item: "planner", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 40 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 5 } ] },
{ item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: "B", qty: 15 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 35 } ] }
```

Want output as

```
{ "_id" : "A", totalQty : 105 }
{ "_id" : "B", totalQty :35 }
{ "_id" : "C", totalQty : 55 }
```

Try to do :

```
db.inventory.aggregate([
    {$group : {_id: "$instock.warehouse", totalQty : {$sum: "$instock.qty"}}}
])
```

But it's not working. There may be an item for which there is no `instock` field.

And what if we want each element of '`instock`' as a separate document in a new collection('`inventoryNew`').

The collection is from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way just need to deconstruct the `instock` array using [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) before `$group`,

- `$unwind` deconstruct
- `$group` by `instock.warehouse` and then sum `instock.qty` that you already did

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$instock" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$instock.warehouse",
      totalQty: { $sum: "$instock.qty" }
    }
  }
])
```

Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/WIHu4KaEq3l